# jquery setting form field value

Tags: jquery

Hi I'm new to jQuery but I'm trying to set the form input '#textBox''s value equal to the factorial of what the user inputted. I've done something like that on jsfiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/qizzle/6wf97kzz/

but what I want to know is is there a better way to set the value to the factorial of the input?

```
$('#submitMe').click(function(){
        var tmp = factorial($('#textBox').val());
        $('#textBox').val(tmp);
    });
```

is there a more elegant way of setting the value to a version of itself?

Comment: no, there is not, that is it.

Comment: you could merge both lines into one. (not saying this would be more elegant) but that's about it.

Comment: like @TimHallyburton said, it would look like that: `$('#textBox').val(factorial($('#textBox').val()));`

Comment: YOu could trigger it on the event the user leaves. That way they do not have to click submit me. Though I feel to many worry about elegance of code, and not functionality. It is good though to start thinking in those terms.

Comment: Just a suggestion - If you want to be more elegant, learn Angular.